# VS Code Kubernetes Extension You must be logged into Server

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code

In the [VS Code Kubernetes Extension](https://open-vsx.org/extension/ms-kubernetes-tools/vscode-kubernetes-tools), I am getting an error when I try to Access resources in my cluster.

I have updated my ~/.kube/config with the correct data and general format

### .kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: M1ekNDQWMrZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURB...
    server: https://{yadayada}.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eventplatform
      command: aws
```

### ERROR

[image]

Comment: when you run `aws --region us-east-1 eks get-token --cluster-name eventplatform` in your terminal, outside of vscode, how does _it_ acquire AWS credentials? Because that's likely what's going on here -- vscode (the application) doesn't have access to your AWS credentials so when it launches `kubectl`, and `kubectl` launches `aws`, that interior `aws` has no creds, and sad-trombone

Comment: I always set them directly in the terminal. Should be storing them as ENV variables in the `aws/config` and `.aws/credentials` file?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to add my AWS credential ENV variables:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: M1ekNDQWMrZ0F3SUJBZ0lCQURB...
    server: https://{yadayada}.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
current-context: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:{yada}:cluster/eventplatform
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - us-east-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - eventplatform
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        value: {SOME_VALUES}
      - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
        value: {SOME_OTHER_VALUES}
      - name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
        value: {SOME_OTHER_OTHER_VALUES}
```

Comment: That's a fine temporary solution, but the fact that you have `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` in there leads me to believe it's the result of an `aws sts assume-role` invocation, or `aws-vault`, or similar. Just watch out for the session expiring because kubectl doesn't know that's going to happen

Comment: Yes the pain with this is that I'd have to manually update this on expiration which is roughly a every 4 hours. You're right it's a role I'm assuming. I was about to write a script to just automatically update the `.kube/config` file when invoke a command that calls the role.

Unless there's an easier solution...

Comment: "Easier" is a relative term on the Internet; I mentioned [`aws-vault`](https://github.com/99designs/aws-vault#readme) because it's how I've solved that problem, but [aws `credential_process`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-sourcing-external.html) is another fine way, and then your `args` would  be updated to include `["--profile", "whatever"]` so it knows how to obtain the creds for the `get-token`